# split function in Report Builder 3

Tags: split, reportbuilder3.0

Im creating a report using ReportBuilder 3.0 that will split a field and do some math functions.

Here's my sample data

```
CartonID CartonRange TotalCarton
-------- ----------- -----------
A        1-1         1
B        2-2         1
C        3-10        8
D        11-12       2
E        13-13       1
```

I want to compute the value of TotalCarton using this pseudocode

```
a. split(CartonRange,"-")
b. TotalCarton = 1 + (int.Parse(splitVal[1]) - int.Parse(splitVal[0]))
```

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You can add a user defined function using vb or in one expression using `instr`.

```
= right(val, len(val)-instr(val, "-")) - left(val, instr(val, "-") - 1)
```

other examples at [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms157328%28v=sql.90%29.aspx)